# Flipbook (turn.js) turns once then breaks in IE9 and Chrome for iPhone

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I have a flipbook working fine in most browsers but after turning once it breaks in IE9 and Chrome for iPhone.

Oh and totally a mess in IE8 too, but not focusing on that just yet ;-)

http://www.theseamstressofbloomsbury.co.uk/lookbook

Any tips for troubleshooting?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops, there was a jQuery error causing the whole thing to break in IE8 and 9. Embarrassing!

In case it helps anyone else with IE issues, I used SauceLabs to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

CSS 3 animations are only available in IE10 and later. see caniuse.com

for IE9 and earlier you should fallback to DHTML animations using setTimer.... the jquery plugin vender should have provided a gracefull fallback.

or

you could use the latest version of jquery.mobile that supports ms prefixed css3 animations AND provides a fallback DHTML animation for webbrowsers that do not support css3 animations.

you can feature test for css animation support with
if(document.body.style.transform) or if(document.body.style.animationName)

see jquery.mobile hasFeature object.

Comment: Thanks Rob. The page is meant to fallback to using another script if it fails 'Modernizr.csstransforms'. Am investigating now if there are any js errors that might be causing the problem.